Getting rowversion (timestamp) bytes to display value from database correctly?
I am looking for a solution to retrieve the hex I am storing in my VersionNum column of my database which is of type (timestamp, not null). I am using a SQL Server database.



VersionNum (timestamp, not null)




0x0000000000007DA1



My model class:
public class Message : BoBase
{
        public int MessageId { get; set; }

        public string MessageText { get; set; }
        public int OrderBy { get; set; }

        public DateTime BeginDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndingDate { get; set; }

        public bool IsModal { get; set; }
        
        public byte[] VersionNum { get; set; }
}

My DataObject method GetMessages:
List<Message> messages = new List<Message>();

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "uspMessages_GetList";

        using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                messages.Add(new Message
                        {
                            MessageId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["MessageId"].ToString()),
                            MessageText = dr["Message"].ToString(),
                            OrderBy = Convert.ToInt32(dr["orderBy"].ToString()),
                            IsModal = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["IsModal"]),
                            BeginDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["BeginDate"]),
                            EndingDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["EndingDate"]),
                            VersionNum = (byte[])dr["VersionNum"]
                        });
            }
        }
    }
}

return messages;

When this query returns with data, it is only returning '{byte[8]}' for the VersionNum column rather than the hex (0x0000000000007DA1) stored in it.
I am wondering if I am not assigning it in my DataReader correctly or there is a method I am missing to get the value of the timestamp type column correctly?

Hex is a display thing, byte array is the storage value. If you need to display the byte array as Hex, there's a bunch of code on stackoverflow that does. Or perhaps I misunderstand the issue

Have you tried reading the SqlDataReader documentation? There's a GetBytes method that would seem appropriate.

@siggemannen that is exactly what I am trying to accomplish, but, I can't see to find any working examples on stack of this.. could you be so kind as to point me to one? I may not be properly searching the issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa perhaps? But can you explain why you want to display this? Most users don't do binary or hex

I am using it for modal message notifications version numbers. When my user clicks an OK button on the modal I am storing the message ID and versionNumber in a UserReadMessages table. In the instance that a message has previously been shown, but an edit has been made to the message, I need that version number to compare to my UseraReadMessages table and display the updated edited version.
